# google chrome lag while selecting or hightlighting texts

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Google Chrome lags and sometimes stops working if I select or highlight a text, also the same issue happens with the inspect panel. Google Chrome developers' version works perfectly with no problems only the stable original Chrome facing this issue. I hope anyone can help

I appreciate your answers in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.